# Why the Selenium xpath to scrape ab table is NOT matching, although an attribute is unique given

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I try to scrape the NASDAQ values from the [www.n-tv.de](http://www.n-tv.de) website.
I'm crawling with SELENIUM through the Sites.
The Stock Values are on the Site in Tables.

The Source COde of Table for Example is like:

```
<div class="tableholder">
  <table class="cnttable zebra to le">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th class="ri">Kurs</th><th class="ri">%</th><th class="ri">Absolut</th><th class="ri hidden-xs-down">Relation</th><th class="ri hidden-xs-down">Zeit</th><th class="ri hidden-xs-down hidden-sm-down">Handelsvolumen</th><th class="hidden-xs-down hidden-sm-down">ISIN</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
      <tr class="linked" onclick="document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/aktien/activision-blizzard-295693';">
        <td>Activision Blizzard</td>
        <td class="ri"><span class="icon_neg">66,53$</span></td>
        <td class="ri"><span class="neg">-1,42%</span></td>
        <td class="ri"><span class="neg">-0,96</span></td>
        <td class="relation hidden-xs-down"><span class="neg">&nbsp;<span><span></span></span><span style="border-width: 24px;"></span></span></td>
        <td class="ri hidden-xs-down">31.12.</td>
        <td class="ri hidden-xs-down hidden-sm-down">8 Tsd.</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs-down hidden-sm-down">US00507V1098</td>
      </tr>
  
      
      ...
  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

SO I do not understand the following Problem:

Seachrching the Web Elements of NASDAQ table i will do per Xpath  :

```
nasdaq = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="cnttable zebra to le"]')
       
rows_nasdaq = nasdaq.find_elements_by_class_name('linked')
```

I have made another solution, that works correctly by searching the tableholder elements (3 on this site) and after listing them then taking only the third object, but i really want to understand, **why that xpath selctor above is not working to this the element , although i have the class name unique on this site as an attribute of the table tag element.**

I do not use css or something, has someone an idea, why in this case the xpath is not matching ??

Comment: Somehow I don't find any of the elements within https://www.n-tv.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assumed yo like to scrape this url https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/suche/?suchbegriff=to%20le.*

You have to wait for element you try to find is present in the DOM and can use [`selenium waits`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for this:

```
nasdaq = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="cnttable zebra to le"]')))
```

**Need to be imported**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

#### Example:

```
....
driver.get('https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/suche/?suchbegriff=to%20le')
nasdaq = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="cnttable zebra to le"]')))

for i in nasdaq.find_elements_by_class_name('linked'):
    print(i.get_attribute('onclick'))
```

#### Output

```
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/swx-sp-tra-leis-tr-303397';
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/aktien/apollo-tourism-+-leisure-1562996';
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/aktien/toqublanmonde--eo-047-11904326';
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/cb-p2p-onl-lend---digbanking-12533785';
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/concinngenddivwomin-leader-3254557';
document.location='https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/concinnity-msos-leaders-39076931';
...
```

---

### EDIT

Based on your comment I got the "link" - Issue, there was no table under url  https://www.n-tv.de/  but the nasdaq is linked by https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/nasdaq-849974 and there I found your table.

So it is not necessary to wait, but it can't hurt either. I have imported the table directly with `pandas` into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
...
driver.get('https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/nasdaq-849974')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="cnttable zebra to le"]')))

pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[3]
```

#### Output

**Note:** *Relation column is empty, cause there is no text stored in it and you can simply drop it, if you like*

| Name | Kurs | % | Absolut | Relation | Zeit | Handelsvolumen | ISIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Activision Blizzard | 67,12$ | -0,44% | -30 | nan | 18:05 | 4 Mio. | US00507V1098 |
| Adobe | 545,25$ | -3,39% | -1912 | nan | 18:05 | 2 Mio. | US00724F1012 |
| Advanced Micro Devices | 141,89$ | -5,55% | -834 | nan | 18:05 | 44 Mio. | US0079031078 |
| Airbnb | 167,86$ | -2,79% | -481 | nan | 18:05 | 2 Mio. | US0090661010 |
| Align Technology | 629,44$ | -2,87% | -1861 | nan | 18:02 | 178 Tsd. | US0162551016 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: thank you for the code, unfortunately it hits even not the nasdaq table element by the xpath. so that means the implicit waits are not the reason why element can't be located ba that xpath.  is the xpath correct ?

Comment: unfortunately even the implicit waits are not matching with that xpath the nasdaq element. so the implicit waits seem not to be the reason why not matching the nsadaq element by that x-path. is there any other idea ?, greetings

Comment: @madmax  link of nasdaq is https://www.n-tv.de/boersenkurse/indizes/nasdaq-849974 not https://www.n-tv.de/  --  Take a look at the EDIT in my answer. Is this what you are looking for?